# Populating a JavaScript Array from a list for Google Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, charts

I'm trying to populate the array in Google Charts by pulling data already existing on the page. This is the array I'm trying to populate:

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Target', 'Actual'],
    ['barchartTitle',  ($barchartTarget),      ($barchartActual)],
  ]);
```

And here is everything I have currently (including the array):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("li.dfwp-item .neo-cqwp-barchart .neo-cqwp-barchartTitle").each(function() {
            barchartTitle = $(this).html();
        });
        $("li.dfwp-item .neo-cqwp-barchart .neo-cqwp-barchartTarget").each(function() {
            barchartTarget = $(this).html();
        });
        $("li.dfwp-item .neo-cqwp-barchart .neo-cqwp-barchartActual").each(function() {
            barchartActual = $(this).html();
        });
    });
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Target', 'Actual'],
    ['barchartTitle',  ($barchartTarget),      ($barchartActual)],
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: '',
colors: ['#515254', '#00B0F0'],
legend: { position: 'top', alignment: 'center', maxLines: 3 }

  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('revenuetarget'));

  chart.draw(data, options);

}
    </script>
<div id="revenuetarget" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: I'm hoping someone would guide me in getting the values from barchartTitle, barchartTarget, barchartActual and building out that array mentioned at the top of the page: 

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Target', 'Actual'],
    ['barchartTitle',  ($barchartTarget),      ($barchartActual)],
  ]);

What I have isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there may be a couple of problems.

First, you are setting your three variables from within a `$(document).ready` block, but the rest of your code runs immediately rather than waiting for the document to be ready. So at the very least you should move the code that fills in the array so that its inside the `$(document).ready` block (or perhaps create another block around that code).

Second, the variable names in the array don't look right. Try this instead:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Month', 'Target', 'Actual'],
  [barchartTitle,  barchartTarget, barchartActual],
]);
```

Lastly, if you declare the three variable without using `var` you may be inserting them into the global scope which may not be what you want. Of course, if you do declare them with `var` make sure you do so at a level that will leave them visible to the code that fills in the array, perhaps like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var barchartTitle;
    var barchartTarget;
    var barchartActual;

    $("li.dfwp-item .neo-cqwp-barchart .neo-cqwp-barchartTitle").each(function() {
        barchartTitle = $(this).html();
    });
    $("li.dfwp-item .neo-cqwp-barchart .neo-cqwp-barchartTarget").each(function() {
        barchartTarget = $(this).html();
    });
    $("li.dfwp-item .neo-cqwp-barchart .neo-cqwp-barchartActual").each(function() {
        barchartActual = $(this).html();
    });

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Target', 'Actual'],
      [barchartTitle, barchartTarget, barchartActual],
    ]);
});
```